# How to drag textarea and inputs using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, textarea, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using `jQuery UI draggable` to drag elements but it does not seem to work on textarea and inputs as they are focused whenever I click on them. Here is a [JSbin Demo](http://jsbin.com/ICEYaZor/1/edit?html,js,output) of the problem.

**HTML**

```
<textarea class="movable" placeholder="I am textarea. Try to move me"></textarea>
<h2></h2>
<div class="movable">I am a DIV. Try to move me</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.movable').draggable();
```

I think I am missing some parameter in `draggable` method which can do this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I have found solution to this problem after some googling. Posting it here to help others. Two steps needed:

1. [jQuery Draggable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel) disables draggable on ***input,textarea,select,button*** elements.
2. To override this, in draggable method, pass this `{ cancel: '' }`

Here is [working JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/ICEYaZor/2/edit?html,js,output)

**HTML**

```
<textarea class="movable" placeholder="I am textarea. Try to move me"></textarea>
<h2></h2>
<div class="movable">I am a DIV. Try to move me</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.movable').draggable({
  cancel: ''
});
```